# MongoDB Spring-data query list count

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-data

I have an easy model

```
@Document(collection = "persons")
public class Person {
    @Id
    private Integer id;
    private String name;
    private Integer age;
    private List<Phone> phones;
    //Getters, setters...
}
```

I have a user with 2 phones and a user with one phone. I want to create a query which returns every person who has more than one phone.
In mongodb shell I solved the query using:

```
db.persons.find({$where: 'this.phones.length > 1'})
```

But in java code I can't reproduce it. I wrote something I think it should works

```
Query query = new Query(Criteria.where("phones.length").gt(1));
return mongoTemplate.find(query, Person.class);
```

But it doesn't

I'm using 
mongodb 2.4
mongo-java-driver-2.11.1
spring 3.2.2
spring-data-commons-1.5.0.Release

Any help will be apreciated!
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, the correct query is

```
new BasicQuery("{ $where: \"this.phones.length > 1\" }")
```